# Cannot turn Bluetooth off

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth

I cannot turn Bluetooth off on my MacBook Pro. I am running 10.7.4 and the option to turn it off is grayed out, both in the toolbar and in System Preferences. I used Onyx to reset permissions but to no avail. Help, please! I am not using any Bluetooth devices and I'm not sure when or how it got turned back on, but I've always made sure it was turned off. My battery is paying the price!

Comment: just to confirm - your account has admin rights?

Comment: That is correct, it does have admin rights.

Comment: I had the same issue, it will turn on and won't let me turn it off.  After a couple of reboots, it turns itself off and everything is back to normal, no more grayed out options, everything works like nothing ever happened.  It might be a bug in 10.7.4.

Answer (score 5):

If I hold the Option key when I click on the Bluetooth preferences, I get this weird little guy:

[image]

Looks like an unlocked lock. When I click it, it asks me to allow `com.apple.preferences.Bluetooth.remoteservice` to make changes:

[image]

After authorizing, the little guy looks like a locked lock and I cannot disable bluetooth:

[image]

*Hence*, perhaps you could do this in reverse order to make the little guy look like an unlocked lock in order to disable bluetooth.

Answer (score 2):

I would install a clean copy of OS X on to an external drive and test to see if your current OS is corrupt. If the hardware doesn't let you turn it on or off with a clean install, you have saved yourself having to back up and erase the internal drive and know to take it in for repair.

If you find it's corruption, you could then run Migration Assistant to take the data from the internal drive to the new clean OS and re-test before doing the erase and copy of a working OS with your personal data and settings.

Answer (score 2):

`rm -rf /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Bluetooth`

It works for me without restarting.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is corrupted bluetooth preferences, which is my best guess, the following should fix it:

Move the following files to your desktop:

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist.lockfile
```

Restart your Mac.

This will force your Mac to forget all it's Bluetooth settings so you will have to re-pair all your devices.

Comment: I have the following:

Comment: ..oops, I have the following: com.apple.BluetoothAudio.plist; com.apple.BluetoothFileExchange.plist; com.apple.BluetoothFileExchange.plist.lockfile; So I see the lockfile, which one for the first one you listed? Btw, thanks for helping, really appreicate it.

Comment: I don't think any of those files you mentioned will do the trick.  Perhaps the issue is that your Mac is not able to create the .plist file due to permissions issues.  Can you try to repair permissions from Disk Utility?

Comment: I repaired permissions with Disk Utility and then restarted the Mac. I went back to the library and no luck with those plists. Bluetooth options still grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing a similar problem in 10.11, I found force quitting the process `blued` resolves the issue.  This can be done either through Activity Monitor or on the commandline via `killall blued`.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem for a very long time. Finally I told Siri to "turn off bluetooth" and somehow it is now fixed for me.

Answer (score -3):

Try to reset your SMC as per instructed  [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9DkJHN6GmQ)

got some answers from [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/9044071?messageID=9044071#9044071?messageID=9044071)